# Combining csv files to single data.fram

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

On my HDD I have three csv files. One called `x.csv` which containes data, one is called `y.csv` which contains a single label for each row in `x` and I have a `headers.csv` which are the names of the columns in `x`.

How do I go about and combine all of these three into a nice data.frame in R?

The output preferably should look something like this with given `x`, `y`, and `headers`:

```
x.csv
0,1,0,1,1
0,1,1,1,0
1,0,0,0,0

y.csv
X, Y, Z

headers.csv
a, b, c, d, e

data.frame:
label, a, b, c, d, e
    X, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1
    Y, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0
    Z, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

Please not that the first column is an actual column, not the rownames since the values in `y.csv`.are not unique and are needed for calculations.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you know anything about the `read.table` and `scan` functions? Or are you starting from absolute zero R knowledge here?

Comment: I have tried a few things but always end up with abominations of data.frames. However, I always do `read.csv`. I am not familiar with the `scan` function.

Comment: Any reason why these 3 files were not saved as 1 csv?

Comment: Its always a good idea to show us what you did so that we get an idea of your level of understanding. Too many people want their homework done here :) Also, we can explain your mistakes and you learn.

Comment: @Spacedman I tried so many things that I don't even remember what I did anymore. It's not like R has a file history :(. It's like throwing a small pebble through a small hoop. Can you remember all the arm movements you made that failed that objective? :)

Comment: have you tried the `history()` function in R?

Comment: That is only valid per R session. Closing R and reopening loses that information. I've been messing around with this for days, rebooting my laptop a few times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df <- read.csv("x.csv", header=F, stringsAsFactors=F)

df_rows <- read.csv("y.csv", header=F, stringsAsFactors=F)

rownames(df) <- df_rows[,1]

df_cols <- read.csv("headers.csv", header=F, stringsAsFactors=F)

colnames(df) <- df_cols[,1]
```

this should work.

Comment: For reading a one-line file of strings, like `y.csv` and `headers.csv`, `scan("y.csv",what="",sep=",")` is a bit neater.

Comment: Perhaps I was mistaked in my question. But the `y` values should be an actual column, no row names. Especially since I need to do calculations with that column and the values are not unique. I upaded my question.

Comment: then use cbind; try the following,  df <- cbind(df, df_rows)

Answer (score 0):

Read your `x`, `y` and `header` file using `read.csv` function

```
df <- data.frame(x, row.names = y)
colnames(df) <- z
```